# First port of entry a Schengen Visa (connecting flights)

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, indian-citizens, cdg

Most questions related to port of entry that I've seen around here are asked in the context of visiting the country and not visiting the issuing country. Mine is different.

This is the first time I'm travelling to Europe. I'm travelling to Italy and Greece (7 nights in Italy, 8 nights in Greece) via Air France flights. I'll first land in Paris CDG airport from Bangalore, India and then I catch a connecting flight Air France flight to Rome, Italy (4 hours gap between flights). I've been issued a Schengen Visa from Greece (as I'll spend the longest duration in Greece) and I'll NOT be deviating from the itinerary presented to Greece Embassy.

Where should I clear my immigration to get the Schengen entry stamp on my passport? Someone told me that I should clear immigration in CDG Paris, but was not sure about this. Could someone clarify this for me? Assuming the above is the case, I also have a follow up question. What if both my flights arrive and depart from the same terminal in CDG Paris?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will clear immigration at CDG as this is your first port of entry into the Schengen zone. The remainder of your flights are effectively "domestic" flights (called *internal flights*) as there are no border controls within the Schengen zone.

Make sure you have all supporting documents for the purpose of your trip, as you may be asked for these at the immigration counter. So, have on hand copies of your hotel reservation, your flight itinerary, if you are being invited a copy of your invitation letter, etc.

Once you arrive at CDG, follow the signs for transit passengers and before you can enter the transit area, you'll go through passport control (as your remaining flights are *internal* (within the zone) and not international flights - you have to cross into a different secured area of the airport).

You will clear *customs* (collect your luggage) at your final destination.

I had the same experience (although at a different airport - Amsterdam) where I was flying KLM to my final destination (which was not in the Netherlands).

Comment: The term for intra-Schengen flights used in the Schengen codes is "internal." I find it useful as the flights are not strictly speaking domestic.

Comment: We are a group of friends meeting at Rome. How do I convince passport control that I'm meeting up with them at Rome? Their flight tickets?

Comment: Passport control will ask you; _"What is the purpose of your trip?"_, _"What is your final destination?"_, _"Can I see your return ticket"_, _"Where are you staying?"_. You don't need to convince them you are meeting in Rome - the purpose of your trip seems to be tourism, so all you have to do is show the same documents you did when you applied for the visa.